# Android Development: Sending and retrieving Custom ListView Items to another Activity?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, favorites

I want to send an item from a custom ListView to another ListView.
I already flagged my intent and made StoreListAdapter class serializible to try fix the problem. Putting android:launchmode="singleTop" in the manifest also didn't work.

It's most certainly my code. I'm not experienced with Android.

When i try to open my favorites page from the mainpage of my app, it crashes, when i add a favorite, it adds one, but not the right one. Then i suddenly can access the favorite page! I don't know what's going on.

currentItem is an instance of StoreItemInfo, which i try to send to the other ListView. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong and why?

My SearchActivity class (browsing through stores, this class works):

```
private void populateStoreListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<StoreItemInfo> adapter= new StoreListAdapter();
    ListView storeMenuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewStores);
    storeMenuList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
    private class StoreListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StoreItemInfo> implements Serializable {
        public StoreListAdapter() {
            super(SearchActivity.this, R.layout.list_item_layout, storeList);
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View storeItemView = convertView; // the view which has to be shown
            if (storeItemView == null) { // if the view somehow isn't there, create it
              storeItemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);
            }

        currentItem = storeList.get(position); // gets item from ArrayList with stores

        TextView nameTxt = (TextView) storeItemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        nameTxt.setText(currentItem.getStoreName());

        TextView addressTxt = (TextView) storeItemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
        addressTxt.setText(currentItem.getStoreAddress());

        TextView cityTxt = (TextView) storeItemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCity);
        cityTxt.setText(currentItem.getStoreCity());

        ImageView storePhoto = (ImageView) storeItemView.findViewById(R.id.imgStore);
        storePhoto.setImageResource(currentItem.getStorePhoto());

        final ImageButton favBtn = (ImageButton) storeItemView.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorite);
        favBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { // here probably something went wrong
                String message = "Your pos is: " + position;
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent addFavorite = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, FavoritesActivity.class);
                addFavorite.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                addFavorite.putExtra("storeItem", currentItem);
                startActivity(addFavorite);
            }
        });

        return storeItemView;
    }
}
```

Favorites class:

```
public class FavoritesActivity extends BaseActivity {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);
    processIntent();
}

private void processIntent() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    StoreItemInfo receivedItem = (StoreItemInfo) intent.getSerializableExtra("storeItem");
    favoriteList.add(receivedItem);
    populateStoreListView();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    intent = getIntent();

}

private void populateStoreListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<StoreItemInfo> adapter= new StoreListAdapter();
    ListView storeMenuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favoriteListView);
    storeMenuList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Now what should i do in my favorites class? I have the same adapter and layout in there. It has to be able to add multiple stores to the favorite list.

Comment: It would help if you could post some additional information.  First, why is the app crashing?  Did you look at the stack trace and try to see what's wrong?  If you can't figure that out, include the stack trace so "we" can help.  Second, put some breakpoints (or debug output) in your onNewIntent() and processIntent() to see if or when they are called.

Comment: Just so we understand you have a ArrayList and you want a certain Item in that ArrayList to show in a new Activity?  Why not just get the position in the ArrayList (putExtra ("ArrayPosition", myInt ) and retrieve that ArrayList position in the new Activity?

Comment: You are right, i will look it all up. Thanks.

Comment: It reads the processIntent and executes this. It does not execute onNewIntent though. So it every time i favorite something it overwrites the whole favourites list.

And thanks Mark! Now it atleast adds the right item, although it still overwrites all the time.

There are no errors in logcat.